# D3 time scale tickFormat doesn't ordered based on the range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
import { scaleTime } from "d3-scale";
import { timeFormat } from "d3-time-format";

const scale = scaleTime().domain([1625747708797, 1625747709671])
.range([0, 1317]);

const ticks = scale.ticks();
const tickFormat = scale.tickFormat(1, '%L');

console.log(ticks.map(tickFormat));
```

The console output is:

```
["800", "900", "000", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600"]
```

Why it doesn't sort the list from start to end:

```
["000", "100", ...., "800"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your dataset was instead over many years and you ran:

```
const tickFormat = scale.tickFormat(1, '%m');
ticks.map(tickFormat);
```

You'd get an array of strings of month numbers ([01-12]), but they'd be out of order because your data is in time order (years, then months, etc).